# Looking for title of a scifi story about a class trip

Tags: story-identification

I read a novel from the mid to late 80's where a class was transported for a survival weekend but the transporter malfunctioned and the group wound up on an unknown planet. I believe the kids were stuck there for a couple before being found. At the end of the book one of survivors journeyed back to the new planet with a type of wagon train of pioneers. Anyone know this book and if so its name?

Comment: Stuck for a couple of what? Seconds? Fortnights? Eons?

Comment: When I saw the title, my first thought was, "Magic School Bus?" Although I guess that's more fantasy, technically.

Comment: Not the answer to the question, but if you liked the premises of that story, you might want to have a look at the (fantasy) novel "The Silver Gryphon" by Mercedes Lackey (which is the third novel of the "Mage Wars" trilogy, which I can also recommend as a whole). The story features two young adults that find their routine trip to their first outpost duty turned into a life-or-death survival challenge by unseen enemies that somehow disabled all their magic (including most of their tools), and I found it extremely captivating reading.

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/253893/book-about-survival-test-on-another-planet

Answer (score 16):

Your description is a bit vague, but this is almost certainly [Tunnel in the Sky by Robert A. Heinlein.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tunnel_in_the_Sky)

In "Tunnel," it's not a class trip, it's the final exam of a survival skills class that almost every high-school student takes.  It's supposed to be for a few days, but a super-nova disrupts the teleportation system for a year or so (Offhand, I'm not positive about how long it was).

Comment: If that is what the OP is looking for, this will make the 6th or 7th time this question has come up here.